# How to use class without (::after) in bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I like to use class without  `(::after)`  in bootstrap:

[image]

Comment: Can you provide more context? What's the reason you want to use it without `::after`? what are you trying to do?

Comment: Will you accept an answer?

Answer (score 2):

An easy way to do this could be to add your own CSS rule like this:

```
.dropdown-toggle::after {
    display: none;
}
```

Or create a class that can be applied to elements that you want to remove the pseudo element from:

```
.no_after::after {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: I would suggest that a custom class name is used to modify the CSS instead of overwriting the bootstrap CSS for the entire site.

Comment: `display: none` means you just hide `:after` not removed.

Comment: They do actually disappear from the DOM tree if you inspect the elements in Chrome for example. So in a sense they are removed.

Comment: thank you., I found the solution.

Answer (score 1):

I just write a basic class for remove `before` and `after` from div. Add below CSS in your stylesheet.

```
.remove-after:after
.remove-before:before, {
   content: none;
}
```

Suppose you have remove `after` from code you just to add `remove-after` class and it'll remove `after` from your element. Try this I hope it'll help you out. Thanks

```
<a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle remove-after"></a>
```